# Test for consecutive numbers in list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list that contains only integers, and I want to check if all the numbers in the list are consecutive (the order of the numbers does not matter).

If there are repeated elements, the function should return False.

Here is my attempt to solve this:

```
def isconsecutive(lst):
    """ 
    Returns True if all numbers in lst can be ordered consecutively, and False otherwise
    """
    if len(set(lst)) == len(lst) and max(lst) - min(lst) == len(lst) - 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

For example:

```
l = [-2,-3,-1,0,1,3,2,5,4]

print(isconsecutive(l))

True
```

Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: Your example list isn't consecutive - it can be re-ordered into consecutive integers, is that what you mean? Can we re-order the list?

Comment: @DanielleM. The order does not matter

Comment: Looks fine to be, but you should remove the if and just return the whole expression

Comment: Yes that's what I mean, the list numbers can be re-ordered into a consecutive sequence

Comment: What about repeated elements?

Comment: I should have been more specific, just edited it to say repeated elements return False

Comment: @Vermillion, then your own solution is actually probably the best. Actually it is the best regardless as you are using  simple math.

Comment: `max(lst) - min(lst) == len(lst) - 1` is way faster and space efficient than creating a set just to test the same exact thing. Also, this Q&A is probably best suited for Code Review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another solution:

```
def is_consecutive(l):
    setl = set(l)
    return len(l) == len(setl) and setl == set(range(min(l), max(l)+1))
```

However, your solution is probably better as you don't store the whole range in memory.

Note that you can always simplify

```
if boolean_expression:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

by

```
return boolean_expression
```

Comment: Nice one Julien ;)

Comment: I would add that `return test` is equal as long as `test` is a boolean, otherwise you're going to have to call `bool`

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo, not really,  `if []` `if {}` etc would both evaluate to False as `if [1]` or if `{1:2}` would evaluate to True.

Comment: @JulienSpronck, you need to add a check that the length of the set  is equal to the length of l to catch repeated elements or you will get false positives.

Comment: Do you have to call `set(l)` twice?

Comment: I would also use `return len(l) == len(st) and st.issuperset(range(min(l), max(l)+1))` creating the set st once.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach in terms of how many times you look at the elements would be to incorporate finding the *min*, *max* and *short circuiting* on any dupe all in one pass, although would probably be beaten by the speed of the builtin functions depending on the inputs:

```
def mn_mx(l):
    mn, mx = float("inf"), float("-inf")
    seen = set()
    for ele in l:
        # if we already saw the ele, end the function
        if ele in seen:
            return False, False
        if ele < mn:
            mn = ele
        if ele > mx:
            mx = ele
        seen.add(ele)
    return mn, mx

def isconsecutive(lst):
    """
    Returns True if all numbers in lst can be ordered consecutively, and False otherwise
    """
    mn, mx = mn_mx(lst)
    # could check either, if mn is False we found a dupe
    if mn is False:
        return False
    # if we get here there are no dupes
    return mx - mn == len(lst) - 1
```